# PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My terminal returns the following error:

PlatformException (PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions., null)

Already checked my Google dev console settings and I can't find a solution.

Comment: There is some useful information written in this article, [How to fix Firestore Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404), that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the security rules on Firebase's database allows you to read and write data.
I.E:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please study the Firebase [documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to understand the consequences of setting these rules: everybody can get the configuration data from your app and use those to modify the data in any way they see fit. While that may be acceptable during development, it is almost certainly a bad idea once you share your app with users.